# How do you expose different subsets of a GraphQL type to different users?

Tags: graphql

I have a User type with many fields on it. I want to expose different fields on it depending on who is querying information about the User. What is a good way to organize this without having many many different types each representing a slightly different view of a user? Here is an example with 4 different types representing different views of the same user. Is there a better way to organize this?

Of course I can make all the fields nullable but that doesn't seem helpful to the developer querying the data.

```
type UserForSelf {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  avatarUrl: String!
  email: String!
  mailingAddress: Address!
  team: Team!
  lastLogin: DateTime!
}

type UserForPublic {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  avatarUrl: String!
}

type UserForAdmin {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  avatarUrl: String!
  email: String!
  team: Team!
  lastLogin: DateTime!
}

type UserForTeamMember {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  avatarUrl: String!
  email: String!
  team: Team!
}
```

Comment: I think there is only two approaches: Make em nullable, or something like what you've got.

Comment: There's also a question of schema design, like you could have a separate schema path for info about the currently-authenticated user, and a separate one for admins to see general user info, or have an `adminData` property on users that returns null if a non-admin tries to access it. For team members it's hard to tell, but that may also work.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `Schema Directives` for this use case.
That basically allows you to only resolve some specific field if the user has permission for it. Otherwise you can return null or throw an error.

So in the end you would have a single type User like this:

```
directive @hasRole(role: String) on FIELD_DEFINITION

type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  avatarUrl: String!
  email: String! @hasRole(role: "USER")
  mailingAddress: Address! @hasRole(role: "USER")
  team: Team! @hasRole(role: "USER")
  lastLogin: DateTime! @hasRole(role: "USER")
}
```

Then you can have a directive resolver kinda like this:

```
const directiveResolvers = {
  ...,
  hasRole: (next, source, {role}, ctx) => {
    const user = getUser()
    if (role === user.role) return next();
    throw new Error(`Must have role: ${role}, you have role: ${user.role}`)
  },
  ...
}
```

If you have a field that only `ADMIN` can query, you would just use the `@hasRole(role: "USER")` directive.

Then your service layer (or your resolver if you don't have a service layer) would be responsible to define *which* User to fetch (if your own user or some user based on ID as long as you have permission).

You can use directives for a lot of different use cases. Here are a few good references:
https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-directive-permissions-authorization-made-easy-54c076b5368e
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/directives/